# Extensions of simple Lie groups with a topological splitting

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, group-cohomology, group-extensions

This is a follow-up to my question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/458326/1770).*

I'm interested in knowing about (finite-dimensional) Lie group extensions, where $G$ is simple and $H$ is connected (and hopefully abelian): $$1\to H\to G'\to G \to 1$$

Specifically, I want to know if it's possible for this sequence to split topologically, but not as groups. This is probably equivalent, at least when $H$ is abelian, to the non-vanishing of the continuous group cohomology $H^2(G, H)$ for some action of $G$ on $H$.

We have a corresponding exact sequence of Lie algebras: $$0\to \mathfrak{h}\to\mathfrak{g}'\to\mathfrak{g}\to 0$$

By Whitehead's second lemma, this sequence always splits. I'm aware that if $G,H$ are simply connected, this splitting lifts to the groups. But is it possible that this lifting is obstructed, while $G'\to G$ still ends up being a trivial fibration of topological spaces?

* In the previous question, the Heisenberg group came up as an example of an extension that splits topologically but not as groups. But the reducibility of the base leads to undesirable properties (let's say it has a "partial splitting") so I'm asking a sharper question.

Comment: If $H$ is abelian, isn't the extension always topologically split? For $p:G'\to G$ is a principal $H$-bundle, which is a trivial bundle iff there is a continuous section. And a continuous section can be given by partition of unity: for a suitable local trivialization $G_i\times H\simeq p^{-1}(G_i)$ and an associated partition of unity $\rho_i$, $f=\sum_i\rho_if_i$ is a global section where $f_i:G_i\to p^{-1}(G_i)$ is a local section.

Comment: @LucelliaKassel That looks right to me. Thanks, I didn't notice this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, indeed, if $H$ is abelian then the Lie group central extensions of $G$ by $H$ are classified by the 2ned continuous cohomology $H^2_c(G; H)$. A good survey can be found in

*Stasheff, James D.*, [**Continuous cohomology of groups and classifying spaces**](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9904-1978-14488-7), Bull. Am. Math. Soc. 84, 513-530 (1978). [ZBL0399.55009](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0399.55009).

In particular, the isomorphism
$$
H^2_c(G; {\mathbb R})\cong H^2(G_u/K; {\mathbb R})
$$
appearing on page 520 of the survey proves that
$$
H^2_c(SL(2, {\mathbb R}); {\mathbb R})\cong H^2(S^2; {\mathbb R})\cong {\mathbb R}.$$
In particular, one obtains a nontrivial central extension of  $SL(2, {\mathbb R})$ by ${\mathbb R}$ (which splits topologically, see the top of the page 516 of the survey).

Comment: Thanks, this looks perfect. It took me some time to understand the argument here, but am I to understand that the isomorphism $\mathbb{C}\otimes \mathfrak{sl}_2 \cong \mathfrak{su}_2$ lets us make use of the Hopf fibration $SU(2)/T \cong S^2$? Nice proof!

Comment: @AndrewDudzik: Right, except it is ${\mathbb C}\otimes su_2\cong sl_2({\mathbb C})$.

Comment: Right, I meant to write $\mathbb{C}\otimes \mathfrak{sl}_2 \cong \mathbb{C}\otimes\mathfrak{su}_2$. Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. Am I right to assume that this also gives such an extension for $SU(2)$? (I know this isn't simple)

Comment: @AndrewDudzik: No, the situation with compact Lie groups is quite different: All central extensions will be trivial. This follows from the isomorphism $H_c^2(G; H)\cong H^2({\mathfrak g}, {\mathfrak k}; H)$, where ${\mathfrak k}$ is the Lie algebra of the maximal compact subgroup $K$ of $G$. If $G$ is compact, then $G=K$ and cohomology vanishes.

Comment: Good point, I was thinking "maximal abelian" instead of "maximal compact". Makes perfect sense!